# EF Core stackoverflow when using navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i'm trying to use eager loading with EF Core but i'm having a stackoverflow error.
I don't know what's the cause of this error but i guess it's because both entities are referencing to each other ?

```
Stack overflow.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]..ctor(Int32)
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method208(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Spark.Database.Entities.DbCharacter>)
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method208(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Spark.Database.Entities.DbCharacter>)
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method208(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Spark.Database.Entities.DbCharacter>)
```

This is my method throwing this exception

```
public async Task<Account> GetAccount(string username)
{
    using (SparkContext context = contextFactory.CreateContext())
    {
        DbAccount entity = await context.Accounts
            .Where(x => x.Username == username)
            .Include(x => x.Characters)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return entity.Adapt<Account>();
    }
}
```

And my entities

```
[Table("accounts")]
public class DbAccount
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public List<DbCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
}

[Table("characters")]
public class DbCharacter
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public byte Level { get; set; }
    
    public DbAccount Account { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is the `Adapt<T>()` method defined? Where is the method at the bottom of that stack trace?

Comment: Adapt is a Mapster extension method for object mapping. My overflow exception is probably coming from this method, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic references. See: [EF Core - circular reference and serializing to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875542/ef-core-circular-reference-and-serializing-to-json)

This is one reason it is better to project results to view models rather than sending entities to the client. Additional benefits include minimizing the payload to just include the data that the view needs. (More efficient queries, less memory and smaller payload sent over the wire.)